# Desktop zoomed in and enlarged in Ubuntu 16.04

Tags: 16.04, nvidia, display-resolution, cuda

Why is my screen looking so off? I would like to revert to the standard size screen please. I don't know why this happened.

[image]

Comment: Did you install anything right before this happened? When you login, can you go to Display settings and see if you can change the resolution?

Answer (score 1):

Before you do anything else, write these two commands for escaping from a login loop on a piece of paper, so if you get stuck in a login loop when booting you will be able to do something about it.

- `sudo chown $(whoami):$(whoami) .Xauthority`
- `sudo dpkg-reconfigure lightdm`

Also write down the link to this answer:  [Ubuntu gets stuck in a login loop](https://askubuntu.com/questions/223501/ubuntu-gets-stuck-in-a-login-loop/223634#223634) which has more detailed information about how to get unstuck from a login loop.

---

In a comment you wrote: *Yes I tried to install cuda*. Installing CUDA in Ubuntu 16.04 is known to cause exactly the same error as you described in your question, the desktop is zoomed in and enlarged to huge proportions, such that the login password input box is way larger than it should be and you can't even see all of the icons in the Launcher at the same time. Your problem may have been caused by the NVIDIA proprietary graphics driver that was installed as a dependency of the NVIDIA CUDA toolkit (*nvidia-cuda-toolkit*). nvidia-cuda-toolkit installs nvidia-367 as a dependency in Ubuntu 16.04. Maybe you will have better luck if you installed the NVIDIA proprietary graphics driver that is recommended for your computer's hardware.

1. Bring up a text-only virtual console from the login screen, using the keyboard combination <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>F3</kbd> and then you will get a text-only console which shows you a login prompt. Login to the console at the login prompt with your username and password.
2. Uninstall NVIDIA CUDA toolkit and the NVIDIA proprietary graphics driver from a text-only console.

   ```
   sudo apt remove nvidia-cuda-toolkit nvidia-*  
   sudo reboot
   ```
3. Identify the recommended proprietary graphics driver for your system. Open the terminal and type:

   ```
   ubuntu-drivers devices
   ```

   If you can't login and get to a terminal yet, you can run the `ubuntu-drivers devices` command from a text-only console, the same way as in Step 1.
4. Install the recommended NVIDIA proprietary graphics driver and reboot.

   ```
   sudo apt install <package-name-of-the-recommended graphics-driver> nvidia-settings  
   sudo reboot
   ```